# Why is an explicit conversion required after checking for null?

Tags: c#

```
int foo;
int? bar;

if (bar != null)
{
    foo = bar; // does not compile
    foo = (int)bar; // compiles
    foo = bar.Value; // compiles
}
```

I've known for a long time that the first statement is incorrect, but it has always bugged me. I've verified that `bar` is not null, so why does the compiler complain?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The type of `bar` is still `int?`, and there's no implicit conversion from `int?` to `int`.

The condition doesn't change the validity of the later code. The same is true for other casts:

```
object x = ...;
if (x is string)
{
    string y = x; // This is still invalid
    string z = (string) x; // This is fine
}
```

The compiler rarely uses the result of one piece of code to affect the validity of another. As another example:

```
bool condition = ...;
string x;
if (condition)
{
    x = "yes";
}
if (!condition)
{
    x = "no";
}
Console.WriteLine(x); // Invalid
```

The last line is invalid because `x` still isn't definitely assigned. *We* know that whatever the value of `x`, we'll enter *one* of those `if` statement bodies... but the compiler doesn't try to figure this out.

Although this may seem dumb, it makes the language rules significantly simpler.

Comment: I think this answers the letter of the question but not the spirit. The spirit of the question is, "Why is `Nullable`'s conversion operator declared `explicit` rather than `implicit`?" '''Edit:''' Actually, it does answer why. My bad.

Answer (score 21):

The comparison is only saying - it is not `null`, Compiler still uses type to see if the assignment can be made.

Following would compile even without null checking.

```
foo = (int)bar;
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler only checks if your program is syntactically correct. It does not care about your null check.

The compiler sees that you may loose information assigning an int? to int and therefore it complains.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this: What if you had a member variable typed as `Nullable<int>`, which was accessed by several threads. Let's look at your code under those circumstances.

```
if(foo != null)
{
    // expensive operation that takes time.
    // what if another thread as nulled foo in the meantime?
    int bar = foo;
}
```